# eliminate return function

Tags: c#

how can i eliminate multiple number of return statements to one statement. example: i hav one if clause, the result of the if clause is true it will return 0. or return 1, the else of the same if contains another if clause. it has also the return value. how can i eleiminate this four return statement to one?

this is the program

```
if (IgC == true)
        {
            if (val1.ToUpper() == val2.ToUpper())
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            if (val1 == val2)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Post the code and you'll get some responses. Without it we'll just be guessing at the logic.

Comment: There's really no good reason for this question. Reducing the number of "return" statements is about as useful as reducing the use of the letter x.

Comment: This looks *a lot* like homework to me, now that I have seen the code.

Comment: If it is homework, then cut and paste coding may not be so helpful at exam time. Hope you use the good advice posted here, and do some more reading :)

Comment: We had a similar restriction to our code in first term CS once. Exactly one return statement for non-void functions ... it just led to if chains and a temporary variable for storing the result. Hardly more readably imho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my guess at the logic...

```
int retVal;

if (condition) 
{
  // statements
  retVal = 0;
}
else 
{
  // statements
  if (otherCondition)
  {
    retVal = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    retVal = 2;
  }
}

return retVal;
```

and with your now-posted update:

```
int retVal;

if (IgC)
   retVal = (val1.ToUpper() == val2.ToUpper()) ? 0 : 1;
else
   retVal = (val1 == val2) ? 0 : 1;

return retVal;
```

I avoid nesting ternary operators or check more than one condition with them, as that makes the code obscure really fast. It is not that the code gets any less efficient if you are more explicit, so the whole thing is solely about readability.

I try to weigh code length and visual complexity against expressiveness, and the if/ternary combination seems to be good middle ground for me.

Comment: Single-Entry/Single-Exit - a fundamental of Dijkstra's Structerd Programming

Comment: Also, you don't really need the else, after the first return statement.

    if (IgC) return (val1.ToUpper() == val2.ToUpper()) ? 0 : 1;
    return (val1 == val2) ? 0 : 1;

Comment: @kajyr: The OP explicitly did not want multiple return statements.

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to use the ternary operator ( ? : )

```
return (IgC && val1.ToUpper() == val2.ToUpper()) || (!IgC && val1==val2) ? 0 : 1;
```

It works like this:

```
return condition_to_check ? result_if_true : result_if_false;
```

Comment: if Igc is false the the rhs of || gets evaluated thus !Igc is redundant, no?

Comment: @Preet Sangha: No, the || and && operators are shortcircuiting.

Comment: Whoops - had another think - yes I see what you mean!

Answer (score 3):

A general comment - because I get the impression that the original question was more about eliminiating multiple returns in general and less about the specific example posted.

In my opinion, the decision about how many exit-points a function has should be driven by making the code clean and easy to read. In the example given, I'd say leaving it as it is (with multiple returns) results in the cleaest code. As other commenters have pointed-out, you can set a 'result variable' in multiple places and drop through to a single return, but does this *really* make the code easier to understand. I'd say it doesn't *in this example*.

I've seen textbooks that say that *all* functions *must* have a single exit point, and I wonder if this is what motivated the question. While this rule may be desirable in an academic sense, I don't think that it works well in the real world of real code.

A good reason *for* consolidating exit-points is the case where you have some 'tail' code that needs to be executed after the function's main logic and before the function exits. In this case, using a 'result variable' and a single return statement makes sense.

Theres no absolute right answer to this. Its about judgement.

Andy

Answer (score 1):

In that case, set the return value to a variable instead of using the return there and return the variable value at the end.

As Paul Alexander said, other cases might require different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I would do like this:

```
bool areEqual = IgC ? val1.Equals(val2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase): val1.Equals(val2, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
return areEqual ? 0 : 1;
```

...or for (perhaps) increased readability:

```
bool areEqual;
if (IgC)
{
    areEqual = val1.Equals(val2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
else
{
    areEqual = val1.Equals(val2, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
}
return areEqual ? 0 : 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple returns aren't bad, just some times harder to maintain. Setting a flag may be "clean," but you are making the computer do more unnecessary work later on, which contributes to global warming :-).

Answer (score 0):

First, it's arguable whether you should change it in the first place. Many times what you have is a good solution and in case of your code it looks good too.

Alternatives are:

1. to declare a variable, assign it in each branch and return at the closing brace of the function

```
     int result = 0;
     if( IgC ) {
       if( val1.ToUpper() == val2.ToUpper() ) {
           result = 0;
       } else {
           result = 1;
       }
    } else {
       if (val1 == val2) {
          result = 0;
       } else {
           result = 1;
       }
    }
    return result;
```

2. to use a set of ternary operators ( condintion ? variant1 : variant2 ). I wouldn't recommend it here - code readability would suffer in my opinion.

Comment: You can't auto refactor the logic in visual studio due to the number of returns

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. The code I suggest is compleely equivalent to the original.

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the return info, and return it in the end, like this:

```
int res = 0;
if(conditionA) res = 0;
else if(conditionB) res = 1;
else if(conditionC) res = 2;
else if(conditionD) res = 0;

return res;
```

Though, I'd usually say it's OK to have more than one return statement...

Answer (score 0):

```
 return IgC?(val1.ToUpper() == val2.ToUpper() ? 0 : 1) : (val1== val2 ? 0 : 1);

    return 1;
```

Comment: The function is intended to do case-insensitive comparison only if IgC variable is true.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
    if (IgC) {
        val1 = val1.ToUpper ();
        val2 = val2.ToUpper ();
    }

    return (val1 == val2)? 0: 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((IgC && (val1.ToUpper() == val2.ToUpper())) || (val1 == val2))
 return 0
return 1;
```

or as a ternary

```
return ((IgC && (val1.ToUpper() == val2.ToUpper())) || (val1 == val2)) ? 0 : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic seems really backwards to me but...

```
    bool valuesAreNotTheSame = true;
    if (IgC)
    {
        if (val1.ToUpper() == val2.ToUpper())
        {
            valuesAreNotTheSame = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (val1 == val2)
        {
            valuesAreNotTheSame = false;
        }
    }
    return valuesAreNotTheSame;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((Igc && val1.ToUpper() == val2.ToUpper()) || (!Igc && val1 == val2)) return 0;

if ((Igc && val1.ToUpper() != val2.ToUpper()) || (!Igc && val1 != val2)) return 1;
```

or you can use this:

```
return ((Igc && val1.ToUpper() == val2.ToUpper()) || (!Igc && val1 == val2)) ? 0 : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is turning into code golf :-) Another approach is to do a case-sensitive comparison first, before you even check IgC.

```
        return (val1==val2)?0:(IgC && (val1.ToUpper()==val2.ToUpper())?0:1);
```

This might have better performance, because if the strings pass a simple comparison then the value of IgC is irrelavent, and you save the expense of a case insensitve comparison.

Of course, if I was maintaining production code I'd much rather see the original example (including the multiple return statements).

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just write this?

```
return (String.Compare(val1, val2, ignoreCase) == 0) ? 0 : 1;
```